# How to find sum of this series using GP formula???

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given G.P:- $1 + 2^{1/n} + 2^{2/n} + . . . + 2^{(N-1)/N}$

My approach:-
We know, $S_{n} = \frac{a(r^n - 1)}{r - 1}$

Hence, here as we have n-1 terms, the formula will be:-
$S_{n-1} = \frac{a(r^{n-1} - 1)}{r - 1}$

We can see, $a = 1$, $r = 2^{1/n}$

Hence, $S_{n-1} = \frac{2^{(n-1)/n} - 1}{2^{1/n} - 1}$

Which is not same as the answer which is:- $\frac{1}{2^{1/n} - 1}$

Am I missing something?

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Here we have $N$ terms.

Comment: How??? Isnt it N-1???

Comment: Nth would be next to this!

Comment: $2^{0/n}$ was 1st, then $2^{1/n}$ is 2nd, then ...

Comment: Basically, nth term is 2^(n-1)/n, yes? Then why my way of working isn't correct?

Comment: Because your last term is $n$th, then you need to find $S_n$, not $S_{n-1}$.

Comment: So in place of n we should use n-1 as that's the last term. Ya?

Comment: Let $a$ is 1st term, $r$ is ratio, $n$ is number of terms, then sum of $n$ terms is $S_n=\frac{a(r^n-1)}{r-1}$. In your sum there are $n$ terms, then you should find $S_n$. $n$th term is $ar^{n-1}$, maybe this fact is confusing you.

Comment: $S_{n-1}$ is sum of $n-1$ terms, that is not the sum you have written in the beginning of your question.

Comment: Um, for example if we have total of 7 terms in GP, to find sum of first 6 terms we will use:-

$S_{6} = \frac{a(r^6 - 1)}{r - 1}$

Similarly if we have total of n terms in a GP and we want to find sum of first n-1 terms then we will use what  I said. 

If we used 6 in above example coz we wanted sum of first 6 terms, then here as we have total of N-1 terms then why arent we using N-1??? I don't know why am I struggling with this! LOL

Comment: nth term is basically the last term. Here last term is representated by n-1 not n. Then why we are considering last term as n and not n-1?

Comment: Do you want to see the exact question? So that you can understand it well? I Can share the link of pdf

Comment: https://coali.org/Past-Papers/View/9231_s22_qp_22

It is Q4(b) where I am stuck! In part (a) I got the correct answer as last term was n. Here in part (b) the last term is  n-1 not n, then using my logic I used in part (a) and explained in this post I am unable to get the correct answer :'(

Comment: Also, if we had last term as $2^{N/N}$ instead of $2^{(N-1)/N}$ then I would agree that we need to find $S_n$ but here its not the case and hence I am confused with why not this $S_{n-1}$?

Comment: If we want to find sum with $n$ terms we need to use $S_n$. Sum with $n-1$ terms is $1+2^{1/n}+2^{2/n}+\ldots+2^{(n-2)/n}$. If it is sum that you need to find, then you should use $S_{n-1}$, but it is not the same sum as in beginning of your question.

Comment: Rohan Shah: $n$ is determined not by power of last term, because $n$th term is not $ar^n$ but $ar^{n-1}$.

Comment: You can try with smaller $n$ to understand better. Let take $n=2$, then 1st term is $a$, 2nd term is $ar$, not $ar^2$.

Comment: Last question @Ivan, thanks for bearing with me!

If last term of this series was $2^{N/N}$ and not $2^{(N-1)/N}$ then what would be the formula in this case for sum of all the terms in GP?

Comment: Number of terms depend on 1st term, ratio and last term. I believe in your problems there are always $N$ rectangles and $N$ terms, then when last term is $2^{N/N}$, then first term is not 1 but $2^{1/N}$, then $S=\frac{2^{1/N}(2^{N/N}-1)}{2^{1/N}-1}=\frac{2^{1/N}}{2^{1/N}-1}$. This corresponds to upper bound for integral.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help Ivan. It was nicely explained by you. Now I get where I was getting confused!

Comment: So here in my original question it will be calculated as:-

$S = \frac{2^{N/N} - 1}{2^{1/N} - 1}$

Comment: I lower bound or upper bound we will always consider N terms! Its just a which will change always! Have I understood it correctly?

Comment: Yes. Both sums have identical $N$ and $r$ but different $a$.

Comment: Got it, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Answer edited.

The sum of the first $N$ terms of a geometric series with first term $a$ and common ratio $r$ is: $a + ar + \ldots + ar^{N-1} =  \frac{a(1-r^N)}{1-r}.$

To see that this finite series has $N$ terms and not $N-1$ terms, write it as:
$$a + ar + \ldots + ar^{N-1} = ar^0 + ar^1 + \ldots + ar^{N-1} = ar^{-1}\underbrace{ \left( r^1 + r^2 + \ldots + r^N \right)}_{N \text{ terms}}\ . $$

Assuming you meant your sequence to be: $1 + 2^{1/N} + 2^{2/N} + . . . + 2^{(N-1)/N},$ then your sequence is the above with $a=1$ and $r = 2^{1/N}.$

Comment: If we consider $S_n = a + ar + \cdots + ar^{n-1}$, then $S_n = \frac{a(1 - r^n)}{1 - r}$.

Comment: I have been using this formula since many years and it always gives correct answer! How come is it wrong for this case?

Comment: Check the formula here:- https://d1whtlypfis84e.cloudfront.net/guides/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/25082146/maxresdefault-21-1024x576.jpg

Comment: You're right. I edited my answer...

Comment: The last term will be n ya? Not n-1

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Please clarify.